# How can I replace the last datapoint in HighStock/HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When updating a chart with live data from my feed I am having some small issues when it comes to the rendering of each candle, which is overlapping lines.

While when a new candle is added the issue seems to resolve itself, each candle seems to be holding multiple entries which is not particularly efficient - especially when  you're updating a one minute candle several times a second.

Upon debugging I can't seem to find the exact function I am looking for, but how can I replace the last entry into the data.

Currently I am using:

```
           chart : {
                events : {
                    load : function () {
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        wSocket.onmessage = function(message) {
                            series.addPoint(JSON.parse(message.data));
                        };
                    }
                }
            },
```

So ideally I would do it by interacting with this series object.

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? Are you doing just multiple addPoint or are there more Highcharts related functions being called?

Comment: I actually managed to get this sorted, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer on how to do this is actually embarrassingly easy - there is a removePoint method which you can call if the data needs to be removed. Here is my code example:

```
   if(md.xData[md.xData.length - 1] === d[0]) {
       md.removePoint(md.xData.length - 1, true);
   }
```

In my case I was needing to check the time which is mapped to the x Data.